# C# Embed File Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, embedded-resource

I have a requirement where I want a user to select a file and it will embed it into my application

I know how to embed a resource manually, however I don't know if there is a way to do it programmatically when the user selects a file.

Comment: Not sure it is even possible

Comment: So you want to decompile the application, embed a resource, and recompile?

Comment: If you mean you want to put the file inside your exe some how, it isn't possible without a dynamic compilation.

Comment: Why do you think you *need* to let the user embed resources? You could just keep the file separate in some well defined location without manipulating the exe, no? Giving some overview of your intended use case you try to solve with the idea of 'resource embedding' could help people here giving you good and useful advice.

Comment: Hi, Basically i need to make a music player where the user would add a song and only need to add it the once, so i was thinking i would need to embed it. However based on comments here i think it would be easier and better to just copy the files to a set location and load them in from there. Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

If you mean actually embed data into your 'application.exe', this is not possible without a second executable to perform the operation. The operating system puts a lock on a running executable, to prevent modifications like this.

If you 100% did want to store data in your executable, it would have to be right at the end of the file. I've tried just dumping some random binary data into the end of an executable, and it *seemed* to run just fine, but there's probably consequences.

What you should probably be doing instead is create and manage a folder on the user's machine -- maybe directly on the hard drive, on their user account, online, or in a folder they choose -- and store files there. Then, load them when needed.

This approach works for all resources. Please specify the resources you are wanting to 'embed' -- and why other approaches are unsuitable -- for better help.

Comment: expanding on second executable: you could create one of those on the fly using inbuilt Emit or CSharpCodeProvider.

Comment: A consequence I can think of is increasing the loading time of the executable. I'm unaware of the intimacies of how an OS like Windows loads an executable, but my first guess would be by loading the whole thing into RAM.